# Qt Widgets do not get showEvent() when tabbed in dock area of QMainWindow

Tags: qt, tabs, widget, docking, qtabbar

In QMainWindow, when few widgets are tabbed together in dock area, how can I detect when a tab has been toggled by user? It is not a problem when I have an instance of QTabWidget created by myself and can attach a handler to currentChanged(), but what's about this case when the main window internally performs  docking/tabifying operations? It normally would be showEvent() triggered but by some reason it doesn't work when tabs are switched. Also, a widget, not on active tab, has it's visibility state turned ON (isVisible() returns true) which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It is QMainWindow::tabifiedDockWidgetActivated() which is signaled when a tab on a docked widget changes. It was added in Qt 5.8. Without it there is no way.